# Cómo hago este pequeño script con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

Me gusta usar varios casos de prueba para mis programas de C++ por lo que utilizo un archivo de texto para probar el codigo, algo asi:

```
   programa.exe<test.txt>resultado.txt
```

Cómo puedo hacer algo similar con python?

Comment: José no entiendo el problema, la redirección de stdout y stdin es exactamente lo mismo (es una característica de la terminal), solo que llamas al interprete Python al que le pasa el script como argumento en vez de a tu programa compilado: `py -3 tu_script.py < test.txt > resultado.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Los `print()` de cualquier script `Python` "viajan" por la salida estándar por lo que `python script.py > salida.txt` funcionará sin problemas, por otro lado, para poder leer y procesar la entrada estándar, puedes:

#### Usar [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line[::-1].strip())
```

Este pequeño script lee la entrada estándar, invierte el orden de los caracteres y quita el salto de linea. Al hacer por último un `print()` redirigimos el resultado a la salida estándar. Por lo que simplemente podrías hacer lo que ya te sugirió @FJSevilla:

```
python tu_script.py < test.txt > resultado.txt
```

Una funcionalidad interesante de la entrada estándar, es poder recibir los datos no de un archivo sino directamente del teclado mediante el uso de `-`, por ejemplo:

```
python tu_script.py -
```